# Retrieve app's icon don't work for all the application

Tags: java, android, package, icons

In my Android app, I show all the applications that are installed on my device and I would like to show the icon for each app.

This is the code that I use to retrieve the icons, using the package's name.

```
Drawable icon = Utils.getAppIconByPackage(context, app.getPackage());
if (icon != null) {
    holder.ivIcon.setImageDrawable(icon);
} else {
    try {
        Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + app.getPackage() + "/" + context.getPackageManager().getApplicationInfo(app.getPackage(), 0).icon);
        Picasso.with(context)
             .load(uri)
             .placeholder(R.drawable.im_app_placeholder)
             .into(holder.ivIcon);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Picasso.with(context)
             .load(ServerUtils.getItemAppIcon(app.getName() + ICON_EXTENSION))
             .placeholder(R.drawable.im_app_placeholder)
             .into(holder.ivIcon);
    }
}
```

The problem is that the icons are not retrieved for all the applications (some has the icon, some other the default placeholder) and I don't understand why, since the package name it's retrieved correctly.

If I need to edit with more code tell me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it worked for me

```
 List<ApplicationInfo> applist = MainActivity.packageManager.getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
                    for (ApplicationInfo info : applist) {

Drawable icon= info.loadIcon(MainActivity.packageManager); //icon of app
}
```

Comment: I assume that your "mainactivity.packagemanager" it's something custom that you wrote and not a default android method that I can use..